# NestJs - Send Response from Exception Filter

Tags: exception, nestjs

I'm trying to achieve a simple behavior: Whenever an exception is thrown I would like to send the error as a response. My kind of naive code looks like this, but doesn't respond at all:

**Exception Filter:**

```js
import { ExceptionFilter, ArgumentsHost, Catch } from '@nestjs/common';

@Catch()
export class AnyExceptionFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
  catch(exception: any, host: ArgumentsHost) {
    return JSON.stringify(
      {
        error: exception,
      },
      null,
      4,
    );
  }
}
```

**Module**

```js
@Module({
  imports: [],
  controllers: [AppController, TestController],
  providers: [AppService, AnyExceptionFilter],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**main.ts**

```js
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.useGlobalFilters(new AnyExceptionFilter());
  await app.listen(1212);
}
bootstrap();
```

Is there anything I miss? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
import { ExceptionFilter, Catch, HttpException, ArgumentsHost, HttpStatus } from '@nestjs/common';

@Catch()
export class AnyExceptionFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
  catch(error: Error, host: ArgumentsHost) {

    const response = host.switchToHttp().getResponse();

    const status = (error instanceof HttpException) ? error.getStatus() : HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;

    response
      .status(status)
      .json(error);
  }
}
```

This code seems to be working fine for me.

Nest version: 5.0.1

Answer (score 1):

Just adding a bit more info about the previous answers. The suggested code provided by [@oto-meskhy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4849298/oto-meskhy) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50927238/9883191) is (replicating it just for completion purposes - credits to [@oto-meskhy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4849298/oto-meskhy)):

```
import { ExceptionFilter, Catch, HttpException, ArgumentsHost, HttpStatus } from '@nestjs/common';

@Catch()
export class AnyExceptionFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
  catch(error: Error, host: ArgumentsHost) {

    const response = host.switchToHttp().getResponse();

    const status = (error instanceof HttpException) ? error.getStatus() : HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;

    response
      .status(status)
      .json(error);
  }
}
```

This code should work IF your NestJS application didn't defined a specific platform in the `NestFactory.create()` method. HoweHowever, if the chosen platform is `Fastify` ([docs here](https://docs.nestjs.com/first-steps#platform)), note that the a small piece of the code above will not work, more specifically:

```
    ...
    response
      .status(status)
      .send(object)
```

In such case, your application code should change a little bit to use `Fastify`'s [Reply methods](https://www.fastify.io/docs/v1.13.x/Reply/), like this:

```
    // fastify
    response
      .code(status)
      .send(error);
```

Answer (score 0):

`catch` has to use the `response` object to send something back to the client:

```
const ctx = host.switchToHttp();
const response = ctx.getResponse();

response
  .status(status)
  .send('Hello');
```

Comment: I already tried that, but this seemed not to work for some reason. The response object hadn't even a function called "status". :-(